# xmlstarlet delete all elements except one from xml data feed

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

On my Debian VPS, I want to keep element only `CategoryName Mobile Phones` and delete all other elements having Category Names such as `Mobile Accessories` `Laptops` etc. total 20 different Category Names. XML file size is big 800 MB.

```
xmlstarlet el -u sd.xml
Products
Products/Product
Products/Product/Brand
Products/Product/CategoryName
Products/Product/CategoryPathAsString
```

Here sample XML :

```
<Products>
<Product>
   <ProductID>92545172</ProductID>
   <ProductSKU>630348288360</ProductSKU>
   <ProductName>Self Snap Aux Connected Selfie Stick</ProductName>
   <ProductDescription>This product is charge free </ProductDescription>
   <ProductPrice>353.00</ProductPrice>
   <ProductPriceCurrency>INR</ProductPriceCurrency>
   <WasPrice>649.00</WasPrice>
   <DiscountedPrice>0.00</DiscountedPrice>
   <ProductURL>http://clk</ProductURL>
   <PID>8053</PID>
   <MID>159526</MID>
   <ProductImageLargeURL>http://</ProductImageLargeURL>
   <StockAvailability>in stock</StockAvailability>
   <Brand>Self Snap</Brand>
   <CategoryName>Camera Accessories</CategoryName>
   <CategoryPathAsString>Root|Cameras &amp; Accessories|Camera Accessories|</CategoryPathAsString>
</Product>
<Product>
   <ProductID>29911116</ProductID>
   <ProductSKU>647266238</ProductSKU>
   <ProductName>Philips 40PFL5059/V7 40 inches Full HD LED Television</ProductName>
   <ProductDescription>LED Display Resolution : 1920 x 1080</ProductDescription>
   <ProductPrice>30196.00</ProductPrice>
   <ProductPriceCurrency>INR</ProductPriceCurrency>
   <WasPrice>39800.00</WasPrice>
   <DiscountedPrice>0.00</DiscountedPrice>
   <ProductURL>http://clk</ProductURL>
   <PID>8053</PID>
   <MID>159526</MID>
   <ProductImageLargeURL>http://n1</ProductImageLargeURL>
   <StockAvailability>in stock</StockAvailability>
   <Brand>Philips</Brand>
   <CategoryName>Televisions</CategoryName>
   <CategoryPathAsString>Root|TVs, Audio &amp; Video|Televisions|</CategoryPathAsString>
</Product>
<Product>
   <ProductID>93959216</ProductID>
   <ProductSKU>683203029</ProductSKU>
   <ProductName>Micromax Canvas Beat A114R</ProductName>
   <ProductDescription>Type : MultiSim Sim : Dual SIM Os Version : Android </ProductDescription>
   <ProductPrice>7999.00</ProductPrice>
   <ProductPriceCurrency>INR</ProductPriceCurrency>
   <WasPrice>9990.00</WasPrice>
   <DiscountedPrice>0.00</DiscountedPrice>
   <ProductURL>http://clk</ProductURL>
   <PID>8053</PID>
   <MID>159526</MID>
   <ProductImageLargeURL>http://n1</ProductImageLargeURL>
   <StockAvailability>in stock</StockAvailability>
   <Brand>Micromax</Brand>
   <CategoryName>Mobile Phones</CategoryName>
   <CategoryPathAsString>Root|Mobiles &amp; Tablets|Mobile Phones|</CategoryPathAsString>
</Product>
</Products>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear without sample XML and expected result XML. Assuming that you want to delete elements named `CategoryName` having inner text not equals to `"Mobile Phones"`, you can try using this xpath :

```
/Products/Product/CategoryName[. != 'Mobile Phones']
```

---

Turned out you want to delete `<Product>` element having child element `<CategoryName>` value not equals to `"Mobile Phones"`. In this case, you can try the following xpath :

```
/Products/Product[CategoryName != 'Mobile Phones']
```

Comment: Please check sample feed url showing products of `CategoryName`    `Camera Accessories` `Televisions` and `Mobile Phones` [feed url](https://goo.gl/fSgNcp) 
I have tried below code
`xmlstarlet ed -d "/Products/Product/CategoryName[. != 'Mobile Phones']" sd.xml`
But not working
I want to keep products only having `CategoryName` `Mobile Phones`

Comment: @Hrishi "not working" is never enough info to allows us to suggest a solution. So next time, please explain what's wrong with that, in what way it isn't working. Anyway, I think I understand the requirement now, see the updated answer.

Comment: I have tried this command `xmlstarlet ed -d "/Products/Product[CategoryName != 'Mobile Phones']" sd.xml` still all products in the xml file are same as it nothing deleted, even file size also the same checked before and after by command  `du -sh *` If my command string is wrong please give me correct string, I am executing this command from the same from the same directory xml data feed file is stored.

Comment: I'm not linux user, but according to [this article](http://www.technomancy.org/xml/delete-node-command-line/) you need to save output of the delete command explicitly like : `xmlstarlet ed -d "/Products/Product[CategoryName != 'Mobile Phones']" sd.xml > sd.xml` (or maybe try to use different file name for output to test)

Comment: Thanks, `xmlstarlet ed -d "/Products/Product[CategoryName != 'Mobile Phones']" sd.xml > sd1.xml` perfect solution. File size reduced to 30MB immediately.